# Why are the number of rows greater than the autoincrement value?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm importing things into MariaDB currently, and the number of listed rows on "SHOW TABLE status" for one of my tables is greater than the auto-increment value. This I find odd, because the auto-increment value I set to be NOT NULL, UNIQUE, and the PRIMARY KEY.

Here's an example of the table with some columns removed for brevity:

```
| Name                           | Rows  | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment |
| my_table_here                  | 10835 |             36 |      393216 |               0 |       262144 |         0 |          10659 |
```

As you can see, it says there are 10835 rows of data, but the counter for the next row is on 10659 which suggests that there are 177 duplicate or null rows. However, when I perform these queries:

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) FROM my_table_here
 SELECT COUNT(id) FROM my_table_here
```

Both of these return 10658 as the value, suggesting that there are in fact no duplicates or null values.

Why does the status table show more rows than actually exist here?

Comment: The number of rows in an estimate not an absolute count.

Comment: "The number of rows in an estimate not an absolute count" Yes and No @Dave "The number of rows. Some storage engines, such as **MyISAM, store the exact count**. For other storage engines, such as **InnoDB, this value is an approximation, and may vary from the actual value by as much as 40% to 50%**. In such cases, use SELECT COUNT(*) to obtain an accurate count. " source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-table-status.html

Comment: Thank you guys for the response. I couldn't find the other question when i searched, but it answers it fine. I do indeed seem to be using InnoDB, in fact.

Comment: @ChthonicOne I know it has been resolved already, but it is also worth noting that auto increment does not constrain the values in the field; it is really quite easy to have more rows than the pending auto-increment value by have rows with negative values for the auto-incremented field.

Comment: Thank you, I understand that though. The program I have written solely uses the autoincrement function from the database, as I never set the id number myself.